# Unable to lookup JNDI name [javax.transaction.TransactionManager]

Tags: java, jboss, vaadin, wildfly

In my JavaEE application I have got two JAR's (Entities, Interfaces), one EJB (Service) and one WAR (Vaadin) projects. The application server is WildFly (JBoss). After deploying project there is an following error. In GlassFish there is everything fine.

> javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [javax.transaction.TransactionManager]
>
> null: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: project1-ear-1.0.0.0/project1-Services-ejb1.0.0.0/PersonServiceImpl!com.domain.project1.interfaces.PersonService -- service jboss.naming.context.java."project1-ear-1.0.0.0"."project1-Services-ejb1.0.0.0"."PersonServiceImpl!com.domain.project1.interfaces.PersonService

My lookup:

> java:global/project1-ear-1.0.0.0/project1-Services-ejb-1.0.0.0/PersonServiceImpl!com.domain.project1.interfaces.PersonService

What's wrong? Thanks for help!

Comment: When you deploy your application on WildFly, what's your JNDI tree like? Also, could you please provide the entire stack trace?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are deploying this on wildfly you need to change the property in the > persistence.xml

provider FROM

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

TO

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

Remove both the hibernate.transaction.jta.platform properties

```
<name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" >

<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform" />
```

and add the below instead

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
```

that should resolve the transaction manager issue.